# CCMenuItemToggle delay... image caching?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I am creating a CCMenuItemToggle like such:

```
CCMenuItemToggle *musicToggle = [CCMenuItemToggle itemWithTarget:self 
                                                           selector:@selector(MusicMute:) items:enableMusic, disableMusic, nil];
```

enableMusic and disableMusic are CCMenuItems created from images as such:

```
CCMenuItem *enableMusic = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"musicbutton.png" 
                                                           selectedImage:@"musicbutton.png" target:nil selector:nil];
```

Now, the first time I tap the toggle button, there is a noticeable delay (I think it is loading the next toggle image). What is the best way to preload this image so this does not happen? The changes happen quickly once it has loaded once...

Comment: It turns out the bottleneck wasn't the CCMenuItem at all... it was what was happening in the action itself (the SimpleAudioEngine was being initialized for the first time, which takes a while). Problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```
    [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"musicbutton.png"];
```

this will preload the image into the textureCache

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the bottleneck wasn't the CCMenuItem at all... it was what was happening in the action itself (the SimpleAudioEngine was being initialized for the first time, which takes a while). Problem solved!